# Assigning rank 2 numpy array to pandas DataFrame column behaves inconsistently

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I’ve noticed that assigning to a `pandas` `DataFrame` column (using the `.loc` indexer) behaves differently depending on what other columns are present in the `DataFrame` and on the exact form of the assignment. Using three example `DataFrame`s:

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame({
    'col1': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
})
#         col1
# 0  [1, 2, 3]
# 1  [4, 5, 6]
# 2  [7, 8, 9]
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({
    'col1': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
    'col2': [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]]
})
#         col1          col2
# 0  [1, 2, 3]  [10, 20, 30]
# 1  [4, 5, 6]  [40, 50, 60]
# 2  [7, 8, 9]  [70, 80, 90]
df3 = pandas.DataFrame({
    'col1': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
    'col2': [1, 2, 3]
})
#         col1  col2
# 0  [1, 2, 3]     1
# 1  [4, 5, 6]     2
# 2  [7, 8, 9]     3
x = numpy.array([[111, 222, 333],
                 [444, 555, 666],
                 [777, 888, 999]])
```

I’ve found the following:

1. `df1`:

   1. `df1.col1 = x`

      Result:

      ```
      df1
      #    col1
      # 0   111
      # 1   444
      # 2   777
      ```
   2. `df1.loc[:, 'col1'] = x`

      Result:

      ```
      df1
      #    col1
      # 0   111
      # 1   444
      # 2   777
      ```
   3. `df1.loc[0:2, 'col1'] = x`

      Result:

      ```
      # […]
      # ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3) into shape (3)
      ```
2. `df2`:

   1. `df2.col1 = x`

      Result:

      ```
      df2
      #    col1          col2
      # 0   111  [10, 20, 30]
      # 1   444  [40, 50, 60]
      # 2   777  [70, 80, 90]
      ```
   2. `df2.loc[:, 'col1'] = x`

      Result:

      ```
      df2
      #    col1          col2
      # 0   111  [10, 20, 30]
      # 1   444  [40, 50, 60]
      # 2   777  [70, 80, 90]
      ```
   3. `df2.loc[0:2, 'col1'] = x`

      Result:

      ```
      # […]
      # ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3) into shape (3)
      ```
3. `df3`:

   1. `df3.col1 = x`

      Result:

      ```
      df3
      #    col1  col2
      # 0   111     1
      # 1   444     2
      # 2   777     3
      ```
   2. `df3.loc[:, 'col1'] = x`

      Result:

      ```
      # ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray
      ```
   3. `df3.loc[0:2, 'col1'] = x`

      Result:

      ```
      # ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray
      ```

So it seems that `df.loc` seems to behave differently if one of the other columns in the `DataFrame` does not have dtype `object`.

My **question** is:

- Why would the presence of other columns make a difference in this kind of assignment?
- Why are the different versions of the assignment not equivalent? In particular, why is the result in the cases which don’t result in `ValueError` that the `DataFrame` column is filled with the values of the *first column* of the `numpy` array?

---

*Note:* I’m not interested in discussing whether it makes sense to assign a column to a `numpy` array in this way. I only want to know about the differences in behavior, and whether this might count as a bug.

Comment: Sorry, I don't plan on going deep into this question, but I will say that in my experience `pandas` doesn't always behave well if you put array-likes in the elements of a `DataFrame`.

Comment: @JohnE I think you’ve got the wrong impression. If this kind of thing is documented to not be recommended/supported, then I’m perfectly fine with any wonky behavior it might show. If that’s *not* the case, though, I think care should be taken so that the API behaves in the most consistent and predictable way possible (least astonishment and all that). So if the pandas documentation says “don’t do this” at any point, I would’ve accepted an answer with a link immediately. My point is, it should be possible to find out whether it’s worth pursuing something like this in a straightforward way.

Comment: @Socob, You might be interested in [this meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373714/generic-dont-do-it-answer).

Comment: Socob:  I deleted my comment since it is better explained by jpp here and in the meta discussion.  I don't think you did anything wrong and this may not be well documented (pandas is known for not having great documentation).  It's more like folklore that a pandas user learns over time (and by reading Q & A here).  @jpp  That's a nice meta discussion, I don't know what you think of my answer, but I did try to make it not merely generic, but specific to what the OP is trying to do.  I share your general confusion about exactly what the best approach is!

Comment: @JohnE, I do like your answer and I've upvoted it :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why would the presence of other columns make a difference in this kind
>   of assignment?

The simple answer is because Pandas checks for mixed types within a dataframe. You can check this for yourself using the same method used in the source code:

```
print(df1._is_mixed_type)  # False
print(df2._is_mixed_type)  # False
print(df3._is_mixed_type)  # True
```

The logic used differs based on the value of `_is_mixed_type`. Specifically, the following test in `_setitem_with_indexer` fails when `_is_mixed_type` is `True` for the inputs you have provided:

```
if len(labels) != value.shape[1]:
    raise ValueError('Must have equal len keys and value '
                     'when setting with an ndarray')
```

In other words, there are more columns in the array than there are columns to assign to in the dataframe.

Is this a bug? In my opinion, any use of lists or arrays in a Pandas dataframe is fraught with danger.<sup>1</sup> The `ValueError` check was added to fix a more important issue ([GH 7551](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7551)).

---

> Why are the different versions of the assignment not equivalent?

The reason why assignment via `df3['col1'] = x` works is because `col1` is an existing series. Try `df3['col3'] = x` and your code will fail with `ValueError`.

Digging deeper, the `__setitem__` method for a datframe, for which `df[]` is syntactic sugar, converts the `'col1'` label to a series (if it exists) via `key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)`:

```
def _apply_if_callable(maybe_callable, obj, **kwargs):
    """
    Evaluate possibly callable input using obj and kwargs if it is callable,
    otherwise return as it is
    """
    if callable(maybe_callable):
        return maybe_callable(obj, **kwargs)
    return maybe_callable
```

The logic can then sidestep the checking logic in `_setitem_with_indexer`. You can infer this because we jump to `_setitem_array` instead of `_set_item` when we provide a label for an existing series:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):

    key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)

    if isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, list, Index)):
        self._setitem_array(key, value)
    elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
        self._setitem_frame(key, value)
    else:
        self._set_item(key, value)
```

All the above are implementation details; you should not base your Pandas syntax based on these underlying methods, as they may change going forwards.

---

<sup>1</sup> I would go as far as to say it should be disabled *by default* and only enabled via a setting. It is a hugely inefficient way of storing and manipulating data. Sometimes it offers short-term convenience, but at the expense of obfuscated code down the line.

Comment: Interesting. You haven’t addressed the second part of the question, though. In particular, your explanation doesn’t seem to apply to the line `df3.col1 = x`.

Comment: @Socob, See update. TL; DR: Use lists / arrays in series *at your own risk*.

Comment: And `df.loc[0:len(df), 'col1']` does something different than `df.loc[:, 'col1']` yet again? (Since `df1.loc[0:2, 'col1'] = x` and `df2.loc[0:2, 'col1'] = x` both throw `ValueError`, while `df1.loc[:, 'col1'] = x` and `df2.loc[:, 'col1'] = x` both don’t.)

Comment: @Socob, If I have time, I'll look into the row indexing. Truthfully, it's likely wasted effort. None of this is documented so it's liable to change in new versions with no notice. Especially since it's non-recommended use.

Comment: As I said at the beginning, I’m less concerned with the specific results and more with consistency. From my perspective as a user, I would expect *all* of the assignments in my question to be equivalent. Judging from your statements, I would think that they should probably **all throw an exception**. By the way, is it documented anywhere that this kind of use is not recommended? Otherwise this non-recommendation is, unfortunately, not very useful to users.

Comment: @Socob, It is recorded (or should be) in pretty much all my answers on SO involving lists in `pd.Series` objects. But I'm not sure that counts :). As for `if it doesn't error, expect it to work` I think to understand Pandas well you *must* understand NumPy and the fact that `object` dtype has well-documented deficiencies. It's mentioned in the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#attributes-and-the-raw-ndarray-s), paragraph beginning `If a DataFrame or Panel contains homogeneously-typed data...`.

Answer (score 5):

First, let me attempt a less technical and less rigorous version of @jpp's explanation.  Generally speaking, when you attempt to insert a numpy array into a pandas dataframe, pandas expects them to have the same rank and dimension (e.g. both are 4x2, although it can also be OK if the rank of the numpy array is lower than the pandas section.  It's OK, for example, if the pandas dimension is 4x2 and the numpy dimension is 4x1 or 2x1 -- just read up on [numpy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for more info).

The point of the preceding is simply that when you try to put a 3x3 numpy array into a pandas column of length 3 (basically 3x1), pandas doesn't really have a standard way to handle that, and the inconsistent behavior is simply a result of that.  It would perhaps be better if pandas always raised an exception, but generally speaking pandas attempts to do something, but it just might not be something useful.

Second, (and I realize this is not a literal answer) in the long run I can guarantee you'll be much much better off if you don't spend a lot of time working out the gory details of cramming two dimensional arrays into single pandas columns.  Instead, just follow a more typical pandas approach like the following, which will produce code that (1) behaves more predictably, (2) is more readable, and (3) runs much faster.

```
x = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
y = x * 10
z = x * 100

df = pd.DataFrame( np.hstack((x,y)), columns=['x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3'.split()] )

#   x1 x2 x3  y1  y2  y3
# 0  1  2  3  10  20  30
# 1  4  5  6  40  50  60
# 2  7  8  9  70  80  90

df.loc[:,'x1':'x3'] = z

#     x1   x2   x3  y1  y2  y3
# 0  100  200  300  10  20  30
# 1  400  500  600  40  50  60
# 2  700  800  900  70  80  90
```

I kept this as a simple index but it looks perhaps like what you are trying to do is set up a more hierarchical structure, and pandas can help there, with a feature called a [MultiIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html).  In this case the result is cleaner syntax but note that it can be more complicated to use in other cases (not worth going into details here):

```
df = pd.DataFrame( np.hstack((x,y)), 
     columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product( [list('xy'),list('123')] ) )

df.loc[:,'x'] = z       # now you can replace 'x1':'x3' with 'x'
```

And you probably know this, but it is also extremely easy to extract numpy arrays from dataframes, so you haven't lost anything just by putting the numpy array into multiple columns.  For example, in the multi-index case:

```
df.loc[:,'x'].values

# array([[100, 200, 300],
#        [400, 500, 600],
#        [700, 800, 900]])
```

Comment: I think you should leave this answer! Even though it does not explicitly answer the question, it provides information likely to be useful for future users whose search leads them here

Comment: I do appreciate this answer, even though it goes in a different direction than I intended. It does give a hint to what I was looking for (unsupported/not recommended operations, yet undocumented that this is the case).